# Calling another function inside a Kivy app?

Tags: python, function, kivy

This seems like a pretty simple issue but I just can't figure it out.  I'm using Kivy with Python 2.7.  How do I call the NewFunction() function from inside build(self)?

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout 


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        anchor_layout = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='center', anchor_y='top')
        lblInitiate = Label(text='[color=1f358e][font=tahoma]Hello World[/color][/font]', markup = True, font_size='20sp')
        lblInitiate.size_hint = (0.1, 0.1) 
        anchor_layout.add_widget(lblInitiate)
        return anchor_layout
        NewFunction() 

    def NewFunction(): 
        lblOne = Label(text="[color=1f358e]Test[/color]") 
        return lblOne

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

`self.NewFunction()`

but note that you need to declare NewFunction like this:

`def NewFunction(self):`    <--- **self**

as it's a method of your class.

Comment: That was very simple.  Thank you!

Comment: Plus you need to call self.NewFunction() before 'return' statement in build method.I'd name it new_function() to be pythonic :)